# How can built-in sorting algorithm be so fast?

Tags: sorting, lua, quicksort, lua-table, rosetta-code

Quicksort is said to be one of the most quick algorithms for sorting data inside a list/table/whatever. Anyway how comes the rosettacode Lua implementation of this algorithm

```
function quicksort(t)
    if #t < 2 then return t end
    local pivot = t[1]
    local a, b, c={}, {}, {}
    for _, v in ipairs(t) do
        if v < pivot then a[#a + 1] = v
        elseif v > pivot then c[#c + 1] = v
        else b[#b + 1] = v
        end
    end
    a = quicksort(a)
    c = quicksort(c)
    for _, v in ipairs(b) do a[#a + 1] = v end
    for _, v in ipairs(c) do a[#a + 1] = v end
    return a
end
```

is so much slower (takes about one minute to sort all the random placed entries in a one million entries table) compared to the built-in `table.sort(table)` algorithm, wich only takes about five seconds to sort the same table?

Comment: Lua is interpreted language, and interpretation costs is high. At least try same test with LuaJIT when comparing with native code.

Comment: Quicksort is O(n log n) in the best and average case, but O(n ^ 2) in the worst case. Not always exactly the quickest algorithm out there.

Comment: @Akshat Mahajan Still, this doesn't explain that much loss in efficiency, and I get about the same result if I re create the table in another order.

Comment: @Vlad what does change with the JIT compiler?

Comment: Write it in C. It will be faster.

Comment: @user6245072 LuaJIT will generate native code. Maybe it will be not as good as C implementation compiled with powerful C compiler, but it might be few times faster than interpreted Lua code.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `table.sort` uses quick sort algorithm as well. (See [its code](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltablib.c.html#auxsort))

The major difference is, the built-in one is written in C. Though Lua is fast compared to other scripting languages, it's still not as fast as C.

Comment: So C IS faster than Lua (wich makes sense). But what about C++?

Comment: @user6245072 C++ will still be faster. You can't quite compare scripting languages to compiled ones. There are however things like the already mentioned LuaJIT compiler and Terra (http://terralang.org/) which you can use to get pretty close since they use C underneath.

Comment: Interpreted vs compiled, not scripting vs compiled. Also Lua beats Python on the interpreted side even as a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your pivot to t[2], doubles performance in my compiler, but depending on how you implement quicksort it may break it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the differences in language, Lua's built-in `table.sort` modifies the target table in-place. Your implementation returns a new table, *instantiating 3 new tables per iteration step*. I think that's where most of the performance is lost. When sorting an array of millions of items, those extra table allocations quickly build up!

A more appropiate comparison would be doing *in-place quicksort*:

```
local quicksort do
  local function qhelp(t, l, r)
    if r - l < 1 then return end
    local p = l
    for i = l + 1, r do
      if t[i] < t[p] then
        if i == p + 1 then
          t[p],t[p+1] = t[p+1],t[p]
        else
          t[p],t[p+1],t[i] = t[i],t[p],t[p+1]
        end
        p = p + 1
      end
    end
    qhelp(t, l, p - 1)
    qhelp(t, p + 1, r)
  end

  function quicksort(t)
    qhelp(t, 1, #t)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
local arr = { 1, 5, 2, 17, 11, 3, 1, 22, 2, 37 }
quicksort(arr)
print(table.concat(arr,","))
```

Note that if modifying the input table isn't possible, copying it to a sacrificial table and sorting that one in-place will also be faster than the "pure" implementation.

Comment: I have never seen the use of `do` in such a fashion to prevent polluting the namespace with helper variables. Thank's for sharing!